# Ionic Keyboard shifts background up

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, background, keyboard

The keyboard shifts up the background on both android and ios.

I've tried tirelessly to stop this by using the other questions of similar nature but I have had no success.

Is there a CSS solution to this or a Cordova one?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bring keyboard on top of the page, without pushing content, u need to edit something in AndroidManifest.xml.

You can find this file in platforms/android folder

In that file, you can see below code

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

edit this to

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: It worked perfectly for me on ionic however later versions of ionic the androidmanifest is in the directory - \ platforms \ android \ app \ src \ main \ AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: In Ionic 4 / Capacitor the first line is not there.  You need to add the 2nd line under "<activity" for it to work.
<application
        ...">
        <activity
...
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

Comment: Also this can cause other issues.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567205/opening-keyboard-in-ionic-4-android-app-moves-the-background-image-up