# Opening keyboard in Ionic 4 Android app moves the background image up

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have tried two options in my AndroidManifest.xml

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

With adjust adjustResize it pushes up my background image so that it looks pretty rubbish.  It also allows this weird white section if you scroll down.  See the 2nd and 3rd image.

If I use adjustPan it looks great and fixes the problem but on devices with lower resolution inputs are hidden by the keyboard and users can't get to them as scrolling is not possible.

**Ideally I want the background image to act like adjustPan but the inputs/other content to act like adjustResize.**

Also is it possible to change this setting dynamically e.g. depending on which page you are one?

[image: Normal]

[image: image moved up]

[image: weird white on scroll down]

Edit added code:

```
    <ion-content no-bounce has-bouncing="false" forceOverscroll="false">
      <div class="content">
        <div>
          <ion-img src="./../../../assets/img/branding/logo.png"></ion-img>
        </div>
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formCtrl="ngForm">
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row class="row-padding-one"></ion-row>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col size-sm="6" offset-sm="3" class="input-col">
                <ion-item class="custom-item" lines="none">
                  <ion-input 
                    class="login-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="email"
                    [formControl]="loginForm.controls['email']"
                    placeholder="E-Mail"
                    required>
                  </ion-input>
                  <div *ngFor="let validation of loginValidationMessages.email">
                    <div class="error-message"
                     *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').hasError(validation.type) && loginForm.get('email').touched">
                      {{validation.message}}</div>
                  </div>
                </ion-item>
...


.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: url("./../../../assets/img/login-bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}
```

Comment: What is your layout?

Comment: Have updated question with code.  Also it is Ionic 4.

Answer (score 1):

try to put background image for ion-content of that page.
This will solve the issue!

Comment: Great.  This fixes the white space issue.  The image still moves up though which is not ideal as on another page I have colored the semi transparent font based on the darkness of the background image at a specific point.

Answer (score 1):

Your can do like this:

```
ion-content{
    --background: url('../../assets/imgs/background-image.png') 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

it will resize your inputs and other content but your Image always will be 100%;

Comment: Great.  This fixes the white space issue.  The image still moves up though which is not ideal as on another page I have colored the semi transparent font based on the darkness of the background image at a specific point.

Comment: This solution actually compresses the background image.  I used this to push it up without compressing it.  The least worst option.  Ideally It would just stay under the keyboard and not move.
 ion-content{
  --background: url("./../../../assets/img/login-bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
  padding: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

add your css to

```
.scroll-content {
  padding-bottom:0!important;
}
```

this is known issue in

> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-pushes-elements-out-of-top-of-view/51212/19

for more info

> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-hides-input-until-i-start-typing/60827/9

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work.  I have updated my question to state Ionic 4, could that be it?